# Clone objects, what makes the difference?

Tags: php

Why should we clone objects? What's the difference? What is happening behind the scene when we clone object? Maybe using low resources to make another object?

Comment: [The first paragraph of this doc sums up all your questions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php). Sometimes I clone objects when for example I want to send multiple copies of the same email from SwiftMailer to different people. Or maybe I want to take a `DateTime` object and `add` to it without modifying the original `DateTime` object. Lots of possibilities.

Comment: Hmmm i see, i was going in wrong direction :)  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You clone objects when you need a copy of an object. If you pass an object around only the reference to it is passed, the object is still the same. This is the reason you can change properties of an object and have that change visible everywhere you use that same object. When cloning you do not create a reference but an exact copy. Changing a property in the copy will not change the original.

Let's look at the following code:

```
$a = new MyClas(); 
$a->myProperty = 'Hello World';
$b = $a
$b->myProperty = 'See You';

echo $a->myProperty . ' / ' . $b->myProperty;
```

This will print "See You / See You"

Not let's look at this example

```
$a = new MyClas(); 
$a->myProperty = 'Hello World';
$b = clone $a
$b->myProperty = 'See You';

echo $a->myProperty . ' / ' . $b->myProperty;
```

The result will be "Hello World / See You"

Comment: Nice example. Thanks. Why they are always downvoting me?

Comment: Well there's an part about cloning right in the PHP documentation. It is common to first look in the docs before asking. So maybe it's RTFM

Answer (score 0):

Pretty broad question....

Why?

Situation, I want a date range between two days ago and two days hence:

```
$dateInterval = DateInterval('P2D');
$date1 = new DateTime();
$date2 = clone $date1;
$date1->sub($dateInterval);
$date2->add($dateInterval);
```

Makes it easy to get the two ends of the date range.... yes, I could have instantiated `$date2` as `new DateTime();` rather than cloning; but if I'd needed to do some additional modifications to $date1 before the clone, and $date2 needed to be based on those changes as well, then clone is a lot easier and doesn't require redoing the `additional modifications`

I can't do `$date2 = $date1` because that will simply be a reference to the same object, and any manipulation done to one is automatically done to the other because it is a reference; but cloning creates a duplicate that is a unique instance in its own right

Comment: Nice, i see now the good side of cloning. Cloning makes unique versions of original object.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning an object simply makes a copy of it. Nothing special is happening behind the scenes.

The benefit is that copying all the properties is automatic. You don't have to write out all the code to copy each property of the original object to the new object. And if you add new properties to the class you don't have to update all the places where you've copied the properties by hand.